# Does Duplication also re-roll Modifiers?

Tags: terraria

When equipment drops it generally has a Modifier on it giving it some extra stats and a prefix.

With the latest update to Terraria adding Journey Mode and the ability to Research and Duplicate items and blocks. while playing around in Journey Mode i saw that i only had to give up 1 Shackle to allow it for duplication, though i didn't give it up because i was more playing around with blocks.

So i am wondering if Journey Mode's Duplication for Equipment also rerolls Modifiers, ie. if i gave up a Demonic Shackles, would i get a different Modifier when i duplicate it? the same? or just regular Shackles?

Answer (score 3):

Duplicated accessories and weapons have no modifier at all. This is pretty easy to test with any of the starting equipment, as it only takes one weapon or accessory to fully research them.